# HystrixCommand annotation - how to do fallback with throw

Tags: java, netflix, hystrix

I am using [@HystrixCommand](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica) to create fallbacks in a java server.

Here is one method i have but the issue im having is im wondering am i allowed to throw in the fall back ?

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "doFallback", commandKey = "doFallbackCommand")
   public Response getGraphPoints(String Id, String position) {

//do some work ... finally create a response

       return a_response;

   }

   public Response doFallback(String Id, String position) {
     //can i do this in hystrix command ? or do i really have to return a Response here?no other method will catch this throw for now
       throw new ServiceUnavailableException("points could not be found");
   }
```

The Reason im asking is that when i run this im getting the following error:

```
ERROR [HystrixTimer-1] [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand] [myserver] failed to processed fallback is the method: 'doFallback'.
```

Comment: Read here https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica#fallback it has some examples as well. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, now i understand a little how hystrix works. Hystrix does not require you to set one fallback method. Unless you want to return a default data or add business logic for that case, it is not necessary. If you throw an exception you'll "confuse" hystrix, so it will throw an HystrixRuntimeException.

I hope it helps.